How can I embed interactive elements to Thinkific?
Specifically exploring ways to embed:

checklists
editable templates that learners can download after filling?

Do you know of any external tool that can be embedded for this purpose?
Still exploring for now. Embedding interactive checklists hosted on different tools. It does not work well.
